# Issues with Fullscreen menu overlay over a fixed navigation

Tags: html, css

I m having a problem that is strange. Here is my code pen I created to show you what I am talking about: http://codepen.io/Buzzlightyear90/pen/NqyoYK?editors=110

here is the html

```
<header>
<div id="menu-button" role="button" title="sweet hamburger">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<nav>

  <div id="box-container">
    <div id="row1">
      <div class="box" id="box1">
        <p>About</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="box2">
        <p>Work</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2">
      <div class="box" id="box3">
        <p>Contact</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="box4">
        <p>Blog</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

here is the css

```
body {
  background: #edebe4;
}

header {
  background: #487C91;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu-button {
  border: 2px solid rgba(41, 37, 47, .3);
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 1);
  padding: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: background 750ms ease-in-out;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.menu-open #menu-button {
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 0);
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: transform 750ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu-button:active .hamburger {
  transition: transform 50ms;
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after,
.hamburger .inner {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  top: -1px;
}

.hamburger .inner {
  top: 9px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 19px;
}

.menu-open .hamburger {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.menu-open #menu-button:active .hamburger {
  transform: scale(.95) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.menu-open .hamburger::before,
.menu-open .hamburger::after,
.menu-open .hamburger .inner {
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 1);
}

.menu-open .hamburger::before {
  transform: translate3d(-4px, 1px, 0) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.menu-open .hamburger .inner {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transition: transform 375ms, background-color 750ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu-open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translate3d(-4px, -1px, 0) rotateZ(45deg);
}

#menu-button {
  border: 2px solid rgba(41, 37, 47, .3);
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 1);
  padding: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  @include transition(background 750ms ease-in-out);
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-open #menu-button {
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 0);
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  @include transition(transform 750ms ease-in-out);
}

#menu-button:active .hamburger {
  @include transition(transform 50ms);
  @include transform(scale(0.95));
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after,
.hamburger .inner {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
  @include transform-origin(100% 50%);
  @include transition(all 750ms ease-in-out);
}

//positions of the small vertical lines within the hamburger
.hamburger::before {
  top: -1px;
}

.hamburger .inner {
  top: 9px;
  @include transform-origin(50% 50%);
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 19px;
}

.menu-open .hamburger {
  @include transform(rotateY(-180deg));
}

.menu-open #menu-button:active .hamburger {
  @include transform(scale(0.95) rotate(-180deg));
}

.menu-open .hamburger::before,
.menu-open .hamburger::after,
.menu-open .hamburger .inner {
  background: rgba(41, 37, 47, 1);
}

.menu-open .hamburger::before {
  @include transform(translate3d(-4px, 1px, 0) rotateZ(-45deg));
}

.menu-open .hamburger .inner {
  @include transform(rotateY(-90deg));
  @include transition(transform 375ms, background-color 750ms ease-in-out);
}

.menu-open .hamburger::after {
  @include transform(translate3d(-4px, 1px, 0) rotateZ(45deg));
}

.menu-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Docker", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  p {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 97px;
  }
}
/******************* menu *********************/

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
}

#box-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Docker", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#row1,
#row2 {
  display: table-row;
}

#row1 div,
#row2 div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box {
  height: 50%;
}

.box p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}

.temp {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#box1,
#box4 {
  background: #ccdcda;
}

#box2,
#box3 {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

I have a fixed header and when I click on the hamburger menu, the fullscreen menu overlay covers all items within the fixed header **except** the hamburger menu. This works well in firefox but in all webkit browsers such as Chrome, Safari and Opera, the full screen layout covers the entire fixed header. I have tried to change the z-index in the fixed element. In those webkit browsers, it either covers everything or hides underneath everything.

What is going on?

Comment: works fine in chrome and its same in firefox too. chrome snapshot: http://screencast.com/t/4VaZLZM2  . what are you really trying to fix in above example?

Comment: what I meant, is if you were to copy and paste the code into a text editor and open it in chrome, it won't work.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but you said that you copy/pasted the code and it didn't work? Just out of curiosity, did you remember to include your files (zepto.js, animate.css) and you were also using a css reset/and prefixer. If you turn those off, it won't work, perhaps you forgot to add them to your notepad doc?

Comment: Are you including the JS on a local version?

Comment: I included the javascript on the local version but it's okay, I solved the problem. It had something to do with positioning and z-index. I still didn't undestand why something that would work in code pen didn't work on my computer even when I included all of the libraries in the file.

Comment: you have to define z-index to your ".hamburger" as you have defined it absolute position (for Cross-browser and cross-devices compatibilities). Most of the cases, if you define any element with absolute, relative or fixed position (except static), you have to define z-index in order to give hierarchy.

Comment: the most simple way to use code from `codepen` is to click on share button and then click on export to zip button.